# start animation when modal closes only on active tab bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I need to start animations when a modal is closed by the user only in the active tab.

The tricky part is that I have 3 tabs within 2 tabs on mobile but on ipad and up behaves as just 2 tabs showing the inner tabs at once.

css transition

```
.bar{
    width: 0%;
    transition-duration: 1350ms !important;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
} 
.bar.animation-stopped {
    width: 0%;
}
```

The final width after animations is calculated and added to the div with jquery as a style width: x%;

The html looks to something like

```
<div class="bar animation-stopped" style="width:85%;"></div>
```

I am removing the animation-stopped class with

```
if ($('.bar').is(':visible')) { 
     $('.bar').removeClass('animation-stopped');
 }
 // or just to control de modal in out
 if ($('#modal').not('.in')) {
    $('.bar').removeClass('animation-stopped');
 }
```

But the animation starts as soon as the pages loads not taking into consideration the modal nor the tabs

Comment: Can you give your full modal code?

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle or snippet of the problem??

Comment: modal was done with bootstrap nothing fancy, fiddle is taking me more than expected because all content is generated dinamically. thanks guys